# SQL Server Reporting Service - Service Manager Error - User Does not have required permission

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have Fresh Install SSRS 2008 R2 on Win2k8 box ( on which i am administrator). After install, When i run Reports Manager, It gives following error

> User 'WIN2008\Tellink' does not have required permissions. Verify that
>   sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account
>   Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed.

I could not find any answer on the web to quickly resolve the problem. Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: I did run IE as an administrator, still no luck. I also check the user has permission on Reporting Service folder on c: drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. And here is solution - Since i was using non built in administrator account to access report manager, i was gettnig the error. I log off as 'WIN2008\Tellink'  and log back in as Administrator Account to acess reports manager. Then i was able to access it.

After that i have added 'WIN2008\Tellink' usr to the usr role.