# SSRS 2008: User Does Not Have Required Permissions

Tags: reporting-services, permissions, ssrs-2008, user-permissions

[image]

I have already researched the following existing SO questions and the links that they reference:

[User '' does not have required permissions, SSRS 2008 on Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433068/user-does-not-have-required-permissions-ssrs-2008-on-windows-8)

[Reporting Services permissions on SQL Server R2 SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389040/reporting-services-permissions-on-sql-server-r2-ssrs)

[SQL Server Reporting Service - Service Manager Error - User Does not have required permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877527/sql-server-reporting-service-service-manager-error-user-does-not-have-requir)

[image]

[image]

I've taken the steps already outlined by these suggested solutions, but even after all that and also logging out and back in, nothing has changed.  In fact my user name was already listed as a System Administrator before I started any of this.

One of the solutions (http://thecodeattic.wordpress.com/category/ssrs/) also mentions a "Folder Settings" area where you can specify roles for a user - "Content Manager," "Publisher," "Browser," "Report Builder," and "My Reports" - but I don't see a way to navigate to this section anywhere.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: So, first, you have to create a folder before you can get to Folder Settings. Since you can't even access the site, no point in worrying about that yet ...

Comment: When you click the "Home" link at the top of SSRS, you get that error, right?

Comment: @KyleHale That's correct.  And there should already be folders on this server; another user can already see and access them.  He's the main admin who has been attempting to fix this permissions issue for me for a while now.

Comment: How did your admin map your account? Are you on a domain? Are you saying that your account is system admin on the server or that your account has been mapped to a SSRS System Admin role and you still can't get access? Also make sure there is nothing funny with the mapping such as DMZ/username.

Comment: I see you have "MyUsername" is the format of that username domain/username?  That may be the issue.  Make sure you have the domain/username in there.

Comment: did you tried ***programmatically*** ?

Answer (score 8):

SSRS has 2 security/role sections available in the web GUI: Folder Settings and Site Settings. The navigation path to get to each is kind of weird.

For Folder Settings, login to the report server (/Reports by default). In SSRS 2012, there's a button in the top toolbar called 'Folder Settings'. I *believe* the link is the same in 2008, but it's been a while since we migrated.

Adding user permissions here allows the named users to run reports. Here you should add your own user account, plus the account used to run reports. In my case (web app), this is my IIS Application Pool identity (IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool).

Site Settings controls who can login to the Report server and access more report metadata. You'll see the 2 roles are System Administrator and System User, so these are all really trusted users. Beyond giving yourself admin, you'll only need to grant permissions to user accounts that do "adminy things", like deploying reports. In my case I've got a local user account that my web application impersonates in order to deploy or delete reports. Users (ReportViewer) don't need this access.

I suspect all you're missing is the Folder Settings (e.g. "permission to run reports") settings, which are accessible from the first page when you login to the report server.

If you don't see that link, try the direct URL:
http://MYREPORTSERVER.COM/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=%2f&SelectedTabId=PropertiesTab

(Tested on 2012 only)

Answer (score 3):

It is important to run your browser (IE) "As Administrator". 
Another important bit is to go to `http://localhost/reports`, not `http://SERVERNAME/reports` !

Than click that "Folder Settings" link. Than follow instructions in that postings above.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same pickle myself with the SSRS 2014 user access settings. 
In my situation I have a folder for each of the company's departments - which are a lot!!

After some digging (well, digging and actually giving/revoking myself the user rights) I realised that:

1) I have to add each user in the root HOME Folder Settings (just with "browser" role)

2) Doing this will grant that user access to every report in every folder!! What the hell's with that, MicroSoft?!?

3) I have to edit each of the folders for which that user **SHOULDN'T** have permissions and remove each of these users manually so that, that particular user(s) will eventually have rights just for the one folder(aka dept) they belong to.

Has someone found a better/faster way of achieving this w/o all the extra, huge, painfull, frustrating manual work of removing an user from all the other folders, except the only one that user should only have access in?

If I add an user just to that folder - w/o adding it in the the HOME folder security - then that user will get the same error message as in the OP's description.

And I think I remember, back in the days of SSRS 2005, a SSRS ReportManager admin user was able to edit/modify this so called profiles. I couldn't find that anywhere in SSRS 2014 Report Manager

Comment: Agreed. This is horrible and needs to be fixed. A Microsoft team developed a vbs app to help with this issue: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlforum/2011/01/03/walkthrough-restrict-the-users-to-see-only-their-folders-via-reporting-services-web-services/

Answer (score 1):

One trick is to run internet explorer 11 in administrator mode.
Then you can add your windows user.

Answer (score 0):

Also, accessing the URLs in an InPrivate IE tab will raise the permission error.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to add my domain account to the local instance:

1. Create a local admin user within Computer Management
2. Download and Launch Edge-Chrome as an administrator (https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/)
3. Ensure you're browsing as a guest by clicking the profile pic to the right of the address bar
4. Launch the reports site e.g. http://yourpc/reports
5. Click on the cog in the top right of the web page, select "site settings"
6. Click "Security" on the left menu and add the user account to Administrator
7. Reboot for luck

This may work in another browser, but haven't tried it.

***EDIT:*** You'll need to add the domain user to the default folders too.