# User '%' does not have required permissions, SSRS 2012 on Windows 7

Tags: reporting-services, windows-7, ssrs-2012

After a fresh install of SQL Server 2012 Developer on my Windows 7 machine, I configure SSRS. Then, in IE (version 11), I try to access the SSRS server at `http://(servername)/Reports`. Windows asks for my username and password. Odd, because I'm an administrator. So I enter my username and password and I get this reply:

User '' does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed.

Researching the issue, I come across a number of answers, including:

[Reporting Services permissions on SQL Server R2 SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389040/reporting-services-permissions-on-sql-server-r2-ssrs)
[SSRS 2008: User Does Not Have Required Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205402/ssrs-2008-user-does-not-have-required-permissions)

The answers to these questions are similar:

1. Run IE as an administrator
2. Add the SSRS URL to Trusted Sites in Security tab of Internet Options
3. Retry SSRS URL
4. On success, add your user to Site Settings and Folder Settings with the appropriate permissions.
5. You should then be able to access SSRS without running IE as administrator

Additional workarounds include disabling UAC and repeating the steps above.

Running IE as an administrator did not work. At step 3. I got the same response as above and was never able to get to the SSRS home page.

Before disabling UAC, are there any other workarounds?

Answer (score 21):

The workaround I found is from [Peter O’Gorman's blog entry](http://popbi.wordpress.com/2013/12/09/ssrs-user-does-not-have-required-permissions-windows-user-account-control-uac-restrictions/).

The steps above are the same, except add the URL to **Local Intranet**, not Trusted Sites:

1. Run IE as an administrator
2. Add the SSRS URL to **Local Intranet** in Security tab of Internet Options
3. Retry SSRS URL
4. On success, add your user to Site Settings and Folder Settings with the appropriate permissions.
5. You should then be able to access SSRS without running IE as administrator

To my pleasant surprise, this worked like a charm. Thanks Peter!

Comment: Step 2, adding the URL to the local intranet, worked for me. Thanks

Comment: I had to additionally restart Internet Explorer, but this worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me. Like @ChaimEliyah I had to restart IE, but after that worked great. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot! Step 2 resolved it for me. I just had to add "http ://localhost" to the sites list. That also resolved it for the "http ://MachineName" url usage

Answer (score 2):

Run IE as an administrator - not Chrome.  I swear I tried this before with no joy.

I don't understand why not Chrome and why administrator.  Maybe Chrome somehow dismisses the elevated permissions.  How does the rsManager know at what level the browser is running anyway?

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      12.0.2000.8
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                        12.0.2000.8
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     6.3.9600.16384
Microsoft MSXML                     3.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     9.11.9600.17498
Microsoft .NET Framework                        4.0.30319.34209
Operating System                        6.3.9600

Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 m

Answer (score 1):

Same steps as Glenn mentioned previously.  I also had to add user to role in two different spots once I was able to access SQL Server Reporting Services - Home. In Folder setting -> security -> new role assignment and site settings -> security -> new role assignment. I added my user as well.

http://techasp.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-fix-reporting-services.html

Answer (score 0):

This works for Reporting Services 2008 onwards

This one has been bugging me for a while, some users have access to the report server others get this error message. While trying to resolve it with a system administrator I came across this post from microsoft support

> For users to navigate to a particular folder, they must have Browser role on 
>   all folders starting at the root folder (the folder named "/" in the
>   item path or "Home" in Report Manager). So you will need to grant
>   those permissions explicitly. By default, permissions are inherited
>   from the parent folder. If there are any breaks in the inheritance,
>   you will need to set those permission explicitly.

What we did as a administrator users, was to navigate to [Reports](http://ourreportsserver/Reports) page, then folder settings and grant the user that does not have permissions Browser rights to the folder. Use could then navigate to the home page and work their way down the tree. the sys admin hadn't granted access to the user at the home level just on the folders and reports that have access to.